# Call a JavaScript function before declaration

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function inside `test.js`:

```
function testing(){
  document.write("<p>Tes1</p>");
}
```

And then a basic HTML page.

Is it possible to call the function before being declared and add this to the page?

```
<p>Test1</p>
```

Because if I include the `test.js` at the bottom of the page, it’s not working. Is there a way to make it work (with a JavaScript file being included at the bottom of the HTML page)?

Comment: *"Is possible to call the function before being declared"* – obviously not.

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Comment: call your function on `window.onload()`

Comment: FWIW, `document.write`, especially in an external file, is somewhere between a bad idea and not possible. This may or may not be related to your issue. It's simply not how you do proper Javascript. You want to use `window.onload` (or similar) to ensure your code runs at the right time, and you want to use `document.getElementBy*(…).appendChild(…)` or `.innerHTML = …` or something to manipulate DOM contents; not `document.write`.

Comment: In the .js file i have only the function, i want to include the file just before </body> and call it immediately after <body> for example. window.onload = function(){ testing(); } after <body>, on the browser i see only what was added in the function, and nothing  after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your `testing()` function call inside `window.onload` callback, like this,

```
window.onload = function(){ testing(); }
```

Comment: If a call the function like you said immediately after <body> the result is that it doesn't show me what is after it

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ testing(); }
</script>
---------------------
<p>Testing</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: And what is the content of `include.js`?

Comment: If I use the above code, on the browser i will ses only Tes1 and nothing after it (like "Testing" paragraph)

Comment: In the include.js (or test.js) i have only the function: function testing(){
  document.write("<p>Tes1</p>");
}

Comment: Well that is because `document.write("<p>Tes1</p>");` when used for the first time, replaces whatever there is in the body with __Tes1__. Consider appending it, like this `document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Tes1</p>"`

Comment: It's possible to add it just after <body>? Sorry, I'm not very good with this.